# Replicate trigger on subscriber in merge replication of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, merge-replication

I have deployed 1 subscriber and 1 publisher server in merge replication configuration of SQL Server. I added a table along with a trigger on that table on publisher and want to replicate that table and trigger on subscriber. I have set 'replicate schema changes' and 'copy user triggers' to true but still the trigger is not replicated on subscriber.

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with merge replication. Despite anything I tried, new schema changes at Publisher were not applied at Subscriber even with `Replicate schema changes` set to `true`. In my case it were new columns not propagated to Subscriber even though they were explicitly checked at Publisher to be replicated, instead the following error was returned during sync:

> Invalid column name 'new_col_name'. (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 207)

I ended up removing merge subscription, adding the new columns at Subscriber and then recreating the subscription. **The same may be done to triggers**.

Note, after removing and recreating Subscription you may need to re-initialize it which will replace all data in Subscriber's articles. If you want to preserve existing subscriber objects/data make sure to set the article property `Action if name is in use` to `Keep existing object unchanged`, see the image below:

[image]

HTH